# Choosing shared or static library with Cargo

Tags: shared-libraries, rust, rust-cargo

I am attempting to modify [Racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer) to emit a shared library instead of an rlib.

To do this, I added `crate-type = ["dylib"]` to the `[lib]` section of the Cargo manifest, then ran `cargo build --lib`.  This worked great, and `libracer.so` was emitted.

Unfortunately, now I could not build the Racer binary, which depends on a static version of the library.  Running `cargo build` complains:

```
   Compiling racer v1.0.0 (file:///home/georgev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/racer)
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `std` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `core` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `collections` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `rustc_unicode` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `alloc` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `libc` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `rand` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
error: aborting due to 7 previous errors
Could not compile `racer`.
```

I changed the `crate-type` to `["dylib", "bin"]`, which allowed the compilation to succeed.  However, `cargo build --lib` will not emit a shared library anymore (only an rlib).

How can I specify which type of library I would like to build, while still allowing said library to be built statically for inclusion in an executable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bin` is not a valid `crate-type` value.  The valid values are `rlib`, `lib`, `staticlib`, and `dylib`.  Changing the crate type to

```
crate-type = ["dylib", "rlib"]
```

will cause the behavior you're after.

The reason that only an rlib is emitted with `["dylib", "bin"]` is because there is currently a Cargo bug that causes invalid values for `crate-type` to only produce an rlib.  I've filed a [pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/1914) to fix the issue.

Comment:  See the Rust Docs here on `crate-type`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html